# Auto encoders to convert black and white image?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, autoencoder

I am trying to get an intuitive understanding of auto encoders and how it works colorizing B/W images my questions are,
What kind of input data and test data is needed? What will be the class labels? How will the colouring be achieved?

Comment: Read [this](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/colorizing-b-w-images-with-gans-in-tensorflow-f444f737db6c).

Comment: Interesting....